# using analytics:reportChart returns nothing

Tags: visualforce, analytics, analytics-api

I am embedding a report chart in a Visualforce page using the 
analytics:reportChart tag. Most of my reports render correctly. However, I am experiencing a curious result. My code is as such:

```
<apex:pageblockSection title="US">
    <apex:panelGrid columns="2" id="gl" width="100%">      
    <analytics:reportChart reportId="00Oj0000003bXh8" size="small"  
    filter="{column:'Opportunity.Region__c.Name', operator:'equals',value:'US'}">
    </analytics:reportChart>
    <analytics:reportChart reportId="00Oj0000003bXpY" size="small"  
    filter="{column:'Opportunity.Region__c.Name', operator:'equals',value:'US'}">
    </analytics:reportChart>
    </apex:panelGrid>
    </apex:pageblockSection>
```

The first report displays with no result. The second displays fine. I used the API describe to find the report IDs as well as the filter options, so I know I have the correct field names for my filter. These reports are based on the same report type as well, and both reports are in the same folder.

I tried running the first report filtered by the value "US" and generated a chart nicely (using front-end report feature). I am at a loss to understand why the report with the same filter would generate on the front end but not when run through Visualforce?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out one of the charts at a time and running each individual <analytics:reportChart> at a time? That would rule out whether its an issue with the two reports on the same page or an issue with the Report itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the issue was solved by removing the filter from the report on the front end. In the analytics:reportChart tag I kept the filter there and now everything runs properly.